# Angular 12 doesn't show source code in browser (ctrl + p)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12

I updated from Angular 10 (I believe) -> Angular 12 and after that my app lost the ability to show me source code in the dev tools. I tried to change the configuration but nothing is helping. Is this maybe a problem with angular itself or am I not seeing something?

This is my angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "microsoft-login": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {},
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/microsoft-login",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": false,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "maximumError": "10kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "microsoft-login:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "microsoft-login:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "microsoft-login:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "microsoft-login:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "microsoft-login:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "microsoft-login"
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "microsoft-login",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0",
        "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.14.2",
        "msal": "^1.4.11",
        "ngx-spinner": "^11.0.1",
        "npm": "^7.14.0",
        "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.1",
        "@angular/cdk-experimental": "^12.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/components-examples": "angular/material2-docs-content#12.0.x",
        "@angular/core": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/google-maps": "^12.0.1",
        "@angular/material": "^12.0.1",
        "@angular/material-experimental": "^12.0.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/youtube-player": "^12.0.1",
        "material-components-web": "12.0.0-canary.b52196498.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
        "tslib": "^2.2.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "4.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/localize": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/imagemin": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.6",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
        "@types/shelljs": "~0.8.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
        "eslint": "^7.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-ban": "^1.5.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^32.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
        "firebase-tools": "^9.10.2",
        "imagemin": "^7.0.1",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
        "light-server": "^2.9.1",
        "lighthouse": "~7.2.0",
        "lighthouse-logger": "~1.2.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "puppeteer": "~8.0.0",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
        "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
        "typescript": "~4.2.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0"
    }
}
```

and tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried a couple of things but it's a dead-end :(
I have source maps
[image]

but in the end, it still doesn't work, any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access the file after building a production build?

Comment: I don't think so :D

for environment and environment.prod
I have 
export const environment = {
  production: false
};

and in the terminal ng serve

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I did an upgrade from 11 to 12. Super weird

Comment: @KeatonBurleson in the end I didn't manage to solve it and returned to 11

Comment: @kolek just answered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 12 source map is missing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647471/angular-12-source-map-is-missing-in-browser)

Answer (score 3):

So I believe I fixed this issue by running the following in my project:

```
$ ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 11 --to 12
```

Now I can see source maps and everything!

Comment: Thanks very much
I was struggling with my Ionic App without debugging after moving to Angular 12