# Why is my debugger broken with links only to main.js

Tags: angular

I am struggling with debugging my angular application. It is an application I inherited and struggling to find why it may not be working.

When I try debug my project open chrome debugger all I get is references to main.js

When I click on these it doesn't take me to the correct source code lines.

[image]

Comment: Nobody can help you unless they see the code. `main.js` is build file so you won't see any linking to your source files unless its running in dev env. What can you do? Check the code and find this `avatar` in top to bottom approach starting from `app.component`

Comment: Yeah, you seem to be looking at a production build. That won’t really be helpful. Use ng serve?

Comment: Just in case you're already using Angular 12: it uses the production build by default. Maybe that's why debugging doesn't work the way it used to be.

Comment: I am using angular 12 - let me take a look.

Comment: Still scratching my head here - cant seem to find out why when clicking on the main.js it doesnt work - is there a command to force ng serve to run the debug build.

Comment: @StephanRauh thanks your answer helped me and i found this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647471/angular-12-source-map-is-missing-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments. Angular 12 defaults to production mode and hence bundles the javascript files.

You can execute the below to run development from Angular 12 onwards.

```
ng serve --configuration development --live-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears because somewhere in your source code, your're trying to access a property of something that doesn't exist.

Do a global search inside your code ".avatar" and be sure the property called just before have a value.

```
// This works
const something = {
    avatar: 'https://myavatar.com'
}
const tryingToAccess = something.avatar;
```

```
// This doesn't work
const something; // avatar was not defined inside

const tryingToAccess = something.avatar; // No avatar property, so the same error will appear.
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo - i do know this, sorry if i was not clear enough - i am trying to work out why the debugger is broken. All the debug line items are main.js and when i click on them do not go to the source code as they should.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Please, paste your angular.json here.