# Angular debugger always stop at main.js

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging

I am having an issue with Angular 13 (13.3.7) and VS Code 1.67.2. Tried all the suggestions found here and still doing the same. It breaks into localhost:4200\main.js. But I don't have any main.js file there.

Please see my angular.json file here. What else should I change?

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "inlineTemplate": false,
          "inlineStyle": false,
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "web.config",
                "input": "src",
                "output": "."
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [{
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "4mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "200kb",
                  "maximumError": "400kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyApp"
}
```

I am using Chrome Debugger and below is my launch.json

```html
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.mjs",
        "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.js"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.mjs",
        "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceFolder}/*",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*",
        "webpack:///*": "*",
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*"
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

It always breaks in this function if it helps.

```html
function AppComponent_div_0_Template(rf, ctx) {
  if (rf & 1) {
    const _r4 = _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵgetCurrentView"]();

    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](0, "div", 4);
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](1, "table");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](2, "tr");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](3, "h2", 5);
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵtext"](4, "Mk3 Portal");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](5, "tr");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelement"](6, "img", 6);
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](7, "tr");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](8, "h5");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementStart"](9, "a", 7);
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵlistener"]("click", function AppComponent_div_0_Template_a_click_9_listener() {
      _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵrestoreView"](_r4);
      const ctx_r3 = _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵnextContext"]();
      return ctx_r3.accountService.login();
    });
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵtext"](10, "Sign In");
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
  }
}
```

P.S: I have tried all the solutions in this post and they didn't work for me: [Why is my debugger broken with links only to main.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007363/why-is-my-debugger-broken-with-links-only-to-main-js/72470115#72470115)

Comment: How do you start your angular app? You may need to choose a configuration with `sourceMap` set to `true`

Comment: Thanks. I have added that too and also using "defaultConfiguration": "development". But i't still doing the same. I am debugging using Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

It might be an issue with VS Code.  Have you tried launching without VS Code?

VS Code uses specific launch files, it might be worth looking at those..

They are usually in a .vscode folder and the file is named launch.json and/or tasks.json.
It's possible there is a reference to main.js in there somehow.

Comment: I checked there and there is nothing related to the main.js. Also, how do I launch without VS Code as you mentioned?

Comment: @Jay you can usually go to a Command Line, into the directory that conatains your package.json and type "ng serve"