# Console log only show one file after I updated the Ionic and Angular and recompiling process becomes slower

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, node-modules

I don't know this is something that I should do with source map stuff or not, but I already set source map to true for tsconfig and angular.json. Nothing changed. The log does not show the proper file name and lines.

[The console log doesn't show the proper detail (file name and lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u6C9.png)

Also the compiling process is slower than before updated version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 12 source map is missing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647471/angular-12-source-map-is-missing-in-browser)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you provided some additional information, like from which version to which have you switched your angular / CLI, how you build / host your project and project settings in angular.json

Comment: I tried the answer of your sugestion, but still doesnt show the proper file name and lines. I used to update my ionic to 6 and angular to 13 (gradually from version 9 because the ionic 6 require angular 13). I use "ionic serve" command to compiling for development purpose.